# Typescript: How can I set an optional parameter if no value is passed in a derived class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a base class:

```
export class ClientBase {

  constructor(private uri: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  // My Various Methods
}
```

I have several classes that derive from the ClientBase

For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class GizmoService extends ClientBase {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)  
  {    
    super(environment.gizmoUri, http);
  }

};
```

So in the GizmoService I want to specifically pass the Uri in one particular case..

So ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class GizmoService extends ClientBase {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, uri?: string)  
  { 
    if (!uri) uri = environment.gizmoUri;
    super(uri, http);
  }

};
```

However I get error message that super must be the first call in the constructor.

How can I get around this without having to make massive changes to the existing code base? (i.e. Not changing every call to pass 2 parameters)

Comment: You don't have to use `super`. But if you must then change parent parameter to optional or send null.

Comment: Either don't use field initializers and/or constructor parameter properties, or call `super()` as the first call.  You could do the latter via  `super(uri || environment.gizmoUri, http);`

Comment: Not sure where the most updated GitHub issue about this is, but [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8277) and [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6908) are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always give the `uri` parameter a default value.

```
@Injectable()
export class GizmoService extends ClientBase {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, uri: string = environment.gizmoUri) { 
    super(uri, http);
  }

}
```

Comment: But if it's injectable how do I pass that uri parameter in?  Do I need some sort of factory service like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771196/typescript-constructor-with-multiple-parameters-and-an-injected-item

Comment: @JDS A service factory seems appropriate in the case where you insist on using dependency injection. Let me know if I can assist further.